# How to not fully hide menu using ECSlidingViewController?

Tags: ios, menu, slidingmenu, sliding, ecslidingviewcontroller

Am using ECSlidingViewController class to show sliding menu=) i want show always a part of menu.  Question is how to not fully hide menu?

Comment: Hi there. Did you find solution for your question? Actually I'm going to fork ECSlidingViewController, but I'm sure that there is solution already.

Comment: @frozen_lion Hi! Look, I changed the decision to use ECSlidingViewController. I recommend to use http://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController . And specific RevealControllerExample3. The result you could see in my app: "Under lock". Good luck!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make full left screen use this :

```
[self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:320.0f];
 self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
```

for right screen :

```
[self.slidingViewController setAnchorLeftPeekAmount:0.0f];
 self.slidingViewController.underRightWidthLayout = ECVariableRevealWidth;
```

Comment: look plz here (http://yadi.sk/d/xsLWlWSrA7qj2) what i want to do... generally is it possible do so?.. thx for answering=)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by `ECSlidingViewController` v1. The internal calculations for animating the top view rely on the top view occupying the full width of the screen.

If you upgrade to `ECSlidingViewController` 2 (iOS 7 only), you can customize the layout.